# Problem with animations from Blender

Tags: unity, animation, blender, rigging, export

I have a model that I made in Blender and also I have a gun reloading animation, the model has a rig. So it appears that the animation of the rigged model is devided into 25 different animations but in Unity I can't play all of them at once, if I play only one animation from 25 it will only animate one object (eg. hands) not the magazine or anything else. My question is how is it usually done to play animations from Blender in Unity properly or make animation properly in Blender.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have many different meshes in the model you're exporting. Typically when you export a model, there will be a **single mesh** even though it may have physically separate parts. The crux of your problem being that animations work on a per mesh basis, so because you have 25 different meshes you're given 25 different animations. Take a [look at this post](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2633) to join all your meshes into one. Hopefully it won't ruin your animation.

Comment: I did it but it doesnt work

Comment: Can you post the .blend file somewhere that we could take a look at it?

Answer (score 0):

Did you export it to Autodesk FBX from Blender? What options are showed in the animation tab when you select the imported model in Unity?

Comment: So I should open the blender model in auto desk maya and export it again?

Comment: I dont think that is necessary just yet. Can you change the Animation type under the Rig tab to 'Generic'? Im using this video tutorial as reference [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y8HnDGtpErs)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by use it with the animator? Let me know how it goes?

Comment: I changed it to generic but it still has a lot of animations I think it is one animation per bone. The animation isn't playing at all though. Maybe I am doing something wrong in the Animator I am very unfamiliar with it.

Comment: In the small window on the bottom right, are you viewing your model there or actually on the game view? Can you retake a screenshot of the animation tab all the way with the small window underneath it that views the model?

Comment: It's the model in Animations tab. It is the part that goes after the second image

Comment: Would you be able to provide a link for the model so I could import it to Unity?